# New nginx + phpfpm installation causes PHP files to download

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, php-fpm

I just finished installing Nginx and PHP-FPM using the steps in guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7). However, the test PHP info page seems to be downloading instead of showing up on the browser.

Here's what the config looks like:

**php.ini**

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep fix_pathinfo=  /etc/php.ini 
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

**/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf** (sections that were changed)

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = nginx
```

**/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params**

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

The run file exists:

```
[root@localhost ~]# file /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock 
/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock: socket
```

The nginx process seems up:

```
root      2438  0.0  0.6 327192 10056 ?        Ss   19:06   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx     2440  0.0  0.2 327192  4540 ?        S    19:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2441  0.0  0.2 327192  4540 ?        S    19:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2442  0.0  0.2 327192  4540 ?        S    19:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2443  0.0  0.2 327192  4540 ?        S    19:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2444  0.0  0.2 327192  4540 ?        S    19:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Yet, the PHP file seems to be downloading instead of loading on the browser - this is a simple info page:

```
[root@localhost html]# pwd
/usr/share/nginx/html
[root@localhost html]# cat info.php 
<? phpinfo(); ?>
[root@localhost html]# ll info.php 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17 Jul 27 19:01 info.php
```

In order check this further, SElinux was set to Permissive, the server was rebooted, but none of those steps worked. And normal HTML files are being served without errors from `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Is there some configuration/parameter/directive that I may have missed while setting this up?

Comment: Did you perform the changes in step four and restart nginx?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Yes, the exact same `default.conf` file was used and nginx was restarted (tried rebooting the server too). Also tried switching the `server_name` value between localhost, 127.0.0.1, the server's IP and the FQDN, none of which worked.

Comment: How does nginx configuration look like?